# Writing range to worksheet with no values using array

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to write range to worksheet only where the values exist? Assuming you can give some special data type to a variable such as null? But obviously null just clears the cell.

for example:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim a(2, 1) As Variant
    a(0, 0) = "a"
    a(1, 0) = Null
    a(2, 0) = "c"
    Selection = a
End Sub
```

Why do I need this? To speed up updating of worksheet values because writing whole array to worksheet is a lot faster than writing a single row.

EDIT1:
So this is what I did:

```
For i = 0 To rowi
    Call CellAddMerged(RngData(1 + i, mvaln), rsrows(j, i), mcol)
Next

Private Sub CellAddMerged(ByRef DestCell As Range, ByVal SourceItems As Collection, ByRef qcolumn As settingscolumns)
Dim sitm As Variant
Select Case qcolumn.Preprocess
Case 1 ' trim
    sitm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim$(SourceItems(1))
Case 2 ' degrees
    If IsNumeric(SourceItems(1)) = True Then
        sitm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Degrees(SourceItems(1))
    Else
        sitm = SourceItems(1)
    End If
Case 3 ' radians
    If IsNumeric(SourceItems(1)) = True Then
        sitm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Radians(SourceItems(1))
    Else
        sitm = SourceItems(1)
    End If
Case Else
    sitm = SourceItems(1)
End Select
If LenB(SourceItems(1)) > 0 Then
    If Opt.ValidationExists(DestCell) = True Then
        DestCell.Validation.Modify Formula1:=DestCell.Validation.Formula1 & listdelim & sitm
    Else
        DestCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=sitm
        If qcolumn.PullDownAllNotOn = True Then DestCell.Validation.ShowError = True Else DestCell.Validation.ShowError = False
    End If
    If LenB(DestCell) = 0 Then DestCell = sitm
End If
End Sub
```

RngData being worksheet range. rsrows(j, i) an array with collections. mcol is some custom class...
I assume I can't increase performance beyond this?

Comment: the code you posted gives no errors and writes to the range as you desired. what's the exact issue you have or what error are you getting? if you provide a picture of your expected output, perhaps that will help us better help you?

Comment: Using `selection` to test this isn't best as requires (I believe) `selection` to be of the same size as the array

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I think the issue is that `a(1, 0) = Null` overwrites data in a cell that OP wants to remain unchanged.

Comment: You could simply loop through the array and add the value to the corresponding cell only when the value is not null. Did you try that? Was it too slow? Maybe quicker would be to merge the array with your values with the array of existing cell values, so the array with your value gets nulls replaced with cell value. And after this merge set the values, but I just guess this would be quicker.

Comment: ^ Agree, you can't write parts of an array to the sheet. Merging an array with existing values might be the fastest option.

Comment: Selection is just for the testing. Also note that not setting`a(1, 0)` would also overwrite all 3 cells in selection.

Comment: If I set worksheet range to a variable and loop through that and change values, will it be faster than lopping through worksheet range? Or is it faster to set values from worksheet range to an array, change values in array and then put array back in worksheet range? (range is could be 1000x10 cells and looking for max ~50ms to change all)

Comment: Quicker _should_ be to use arrays and assign the result to the range. To loop through excel range and operate on it  directly will probably be much slower. I say probably, you have to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

first fill the array with range values, then change wanted array values and finally put array values into range:

```
Dim a() As Variant

a = Selection.Value


a(1, 1) = "a"
a(3, 1) = "c"

Selection.Value = a
```

the array resulting out of a range values is a one-based array

Comment: So does setting all the values to a variable and then back affect performance less than setting each cell on worksheet?

Comment: I guess so, but go and check it out yourself. Of course if the range is small, then the difference is imperceptible

Comment: I'd gladly have the brave downvoter care to explain how to improve my answer